# How do I delete duplicate rows in pandas by a column; but not compare None to None values

Tags: python, pandas

I did a very inefficient loop to implement my solution but there got to be a better approach I can't think of.

My data:

```
|ticker|cusip|
|DIS   | 123 |
|DIS   | None|
|None  | abc |
|None  | xyz |
```

if I sort on cusip with ascending= False and drop_duplicates, it's working to remove the DIS row with cusip is None. But at the same time it's removing bottom rows having tickers None, which I want to keep.

I did find duplicate rows and then did a loop to get each duplicate group and applied drop duplicates which is very inefficient as I have to do a huge loop across 1000's of rows.

Is there an option to ignore None rows for dup check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html?highlight=where#pandas.Series.where) to convert `'None'` values in `NaN` + [`DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html?highlight=dropna#pandas.DataFrame.dropna) with `subset` param.

```
df['cusip'] = df['cusip'].where(~(df['cusip'] == 'None'))
df = df.dropna(subset=['cusip']).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

|  | ticker | cusip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | DIS | 123 |
| 1 | None | abc |
| 2 | None | xyz |

Answer (score 3):

Try `duplicated` and with or condition for None

```
out =  df[~df.duplicated('ticker')|df.ticker.eq('None')]
Out[448]: 
  ticker cusip
0    DIS   123
2   None   abc
3   None   xyz
```

Comment: Doe the above takes sorting into account ? Because I want to keep the row having cusip value.

Comment: @RaviP you can sort the value